# OnClick on ticketid need to open a details of ticket using birt report

Tags: report, birt, maximo

I had a requirement to create a report based on individual user whom having SR waiting for approval, On click on Ticket id the URL's should redirect to SR detailed page where he can check request approve or disapprove.

using hyper link in birt properties unable to pass the ticketid by using below url's

http://google.com/maximo/ui/maximo.jsp?event=loadapp&value=asset&additionaleventvalue=Ticketid

Could you anybody help in this regards.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working?  Do you have the SR detailed page working when you use it as a stand alone report without trying to link to it from the other report?

Comment: I am not trying to link a report, simply trying to open SR details page onclicking the SR Ticket id from the report using html page, the URL configured on column properties (Hyperlink), need to post the ticketid in aboved mentioned URL.

Answer (score 0):

If the cell you made clickable contains the ticketId, go to Properties -> Hyperlink -> Edit...

Select hyperlink type URI, and click the dropdown to the right of 'Location' to go to the Javascript window.

If you're going to use it more than once, I would make the static part of your hyperlink a variable. Then add the ticketId by clicking "column bindings" in the left-lower column in the JavaScript window and selecting the appropriate cells in the middle and right columns. You'd get something like

```
vars["staticPartOfHyperlink"] + row[TICKETID]
```

If you'd rather not use a variable, you can hard-code the static part (don't do this, it's ugly and asking for trouble):

```
"http://google.com/maximo/ui/maximo.jsp?event=loadapp&value=asset&additionaleventvalue=" + row[TICKETID]
```

Comment: Hi Venite, tried as per given step still it will not passing ticketid when onclick the ticket id, by hard-code.